# Variable doesn't expand while passing as a parameter to docker-compose command inside heredoc block

Tags: bash, shell, docker, unix, docker-compose

I was trying to run some docker-compose command over ssh using bash script like below. I mean I have an executable shell script deploy.sh which contains below code snippets

```
ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@142.32.45.2 << EOF
DIR=test
echo \${DIR}
docker-compose --project-name \${DIR} up -d
EOF
```

But the DIR variable doesn't get expanded while passing as a parameter to docker-compose. It executes like below. While `echo \${DIR}` gives correct output i.e **test**.

```
docker-compose --project-name ${DIR} up -d
```

Comment: Do you get the same results when you replace the first line with `DIR=local; bash << EOF`? Did you try `set -x` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@142.32.45.2 <<'EOF'
DIR=test
echo ${DIR}
docker-compose --project-name ${DIR} up -d
EOF
```

Get rid of the \$ - it is preventing your variable expansion.  But on second review, I see that's your intention.  If you want to prevent all variable expansion until your code gets executed on the remote host, try putting the heredoc word in quotes.  That way, the $ gets passed to the script being passed to ssh.

As a second suggestion ( as per my comment below ), I would consider just sending a parameterized script to the remote host and then executing it ( after changing its permissions ).

```
# Make script
cat >compose.sh <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
DIR=$1
docker-compose --project-name $DIR
EOF

scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no compose.sh root@142.32.45.2: 
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@142.32.45.2 chmod +x ./compose.sh \; ./compose.sh test
```

Comment: Please note,  DIR is declared inside the heredoc block. And it is an executable shell script. I mean above code is inside a executable file.  Not outside of the block.  Sorry your answer doesn't help me. But thanks

Comment: FWIW, you may find that adding a -n to the ssh command line will help you in the future.  I've had issues where ssh has taken all of my stdin when I run ssh in a loop.  The particular example you provided here doesn't look to need -n, but it's a good thing to keep in mind.  Many hours were wasted by many people putting an ssh in a while read loop.

Comment: I have already wasted more than 3 days. Tried everything almost including your answer. But that doesn't help. Also notice that echo $DIR works but while pass it as a parameter to docker-compose it doesn't work. Tried your answer too. echo $DIR gives the output but not in docker-compose

Comment: If you add one more echo after the docker-compose I wonder what the output would be.

Comment: Another alternative is using scp to send your script to the remote host.  You can then use ssh to execute it.  The script may do better if it has #!/bin/bash at the top, to make sure that it's being treated with the bash interpreter.    Of course, variable expansion should occur before sending the value to docker-compose, so that is why I'm asking you to see if expansion is working on subsequent lines and to run a script where you are sure that bash is doing it's thing.  I'll update my answer with my suggestion.

Comment: one more echo after docker-compose prints the correct output

Comment: Yes alternatives are there.Actually I am trying to deploy it from Travis and there are some travis env variables which is used inside the script.  But I am wondering why this approach doesn't work ?

Comment: I am puzzled as well.  I suggested alternatives because I couldn't understand why the expansion wasn't happening for you.  I was wondering if the echo works after the docker call.  Also,  the -tt was giving me some bizarre results on my side. After my test script stop executing, I remained on the remote host.  Normally,  I reserve -tt for when I am calling sudo on the remote box (and sudo is configured to disallow remote sudo).