# Why composer runs as root even though it's setuid has been changed to another user

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, file-permissions

I am using official docker php image as base image and installed composer on it. Some snippets from my dockerfile has given below.

```
RUN  set ex \
  # Install Composer
  && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin -- --filename=composer \
  && chown www-data:www-data /usr/local/bin/composer \
  && chmod u+s /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Docker main process runs as root and worker process runs as www-data. When I run `composer install` on my container the vendor dir and composer.lock etc owned by root as the container's main process runs as root. So I had changed owner of the /usr/local/bin/composer to www-data and set u+s setuid on it. You can see it below.

```
/var/www/test # ls -al /usr/local/bin/composer 
-rwsr-sr-x    1 www-data www-data   1875611 Oct 21 00:56 /usr/local/bin/composer
```

But when I run composer install still the vendor dir etc created with root owner. What is wrong I am doing ?

```
-rwxr-x---    1 1000     www-data      2299 Oct 19 06:36 composer.json
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        276423 Oct 21 01:02 composer.lock
drwxr-x---    4 1000     www-data      4096 Oct 19 06:36 drush
-rwxr-x---    1 1000     www-data       414 Oct 19 06:36 load.environment.php
-rwxr-x---    1 1000     www-data       481 Oct 19 06:36 phpunit.xml.dist
drwxr-x---    3 1000     www-data      4096 Oct 19 06:36 scripts
drwxr-xr-x   50 root     root          4096 Oct 21 01:08 vendor
drwxr-x---    7 1000     nginx         4096 Oct 21 01:02 web
```

**Update-1** 
The dir where composer keeps vendor directory is bind mounted named volume. My docker-compose file like below:

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  nginx:
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}.nginx
    build: ./docker/nginx
    image: witbix/nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - drupal:/var/www/${PROJECT_NAME}:cached
    working_dir: /var/www/${PROJECT_NAME}
    environment:
      PROJECT_NAME: ${PROJECT_NAME}
      DOMAIN_NAME: ${DOMAIN_NAME}
      DRUPAL_VERSION: ${DRUPAL_VERSION}
      MYSQL_HOSTNAME: ${PROJECT_NAME}.mariadb
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PORT: ${MYSQL_PORT}
      HOST_USER: ${USER}
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAIN_NAME}"
    networks:
      - drupal

  php:
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}
#    build: ./docker/php
    image: witbix/php
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - drupal:/var/www/${PROJECT_NAME}:cached
    working_dir: /var/www/${PROJECT_NAME}
    environment:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${GITHUB_TOKEN}
    networks:
      - drupal

  mariadb:
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}.mariadb
#    build: ./docker/mariadb
    image: witbix/mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
       MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
       MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - drupal

volumes:
  drupal:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: bind
      device: $PWD/code/drupal
      o: bind
  database:
    driver: local

networks:
  drupal:
    external:
     name: ${NETWORK_NAME}
```

So when I execute `mount` command on my nginx container It gives me below output.

```
/var/www/test # mount
    overlay on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/CYKNPHGSOXMLOUVNEOJ6QITFA2:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/OOOELOMQBXBBMCRFGVOTTOXUTQ:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/SLGSDLE7HYX7AY4JCOWPJIKD73:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/RMB5364TWTFBFY6HFZWJVTROKW:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/JGNFDDFSDHLKE4E63LME3E7QM3:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/STSQQ4PZE25ZTSNMTHBBD6AELJ:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/XJLZ5WXZZF55YINJ7TMCDMIL6G:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/W3DF5PJFB4H57RBOZ44CLWKGEP:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/NKVID7PASLZXXMDWZW6AHFPGOE:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/TQQRV5LAYELBLUBS5D6FPHRI3S,upperdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0865874042b7848d173e19593df0f3397f466450f5f3b8f3d33fc79a33c3f336/diff,workdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0865874042b7848d173e19593df0f3397f466450f5f3b8f3d33fc79a33c3f336/work)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=666)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/vda1 on /etc/resolv.conf type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/vda1 on /etc/hostname type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/dev/vda1 on /etc/hosts type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
shm on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=65536k)
/dev/vda1 on /var/www/test type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
proc on /proc/bus type proc (ro,relatime)
proc on /proc/fs type proc (ro,relatime)
proc on /proc/irq type proc (ro,relatime)
proc on /proc/sys type proc (ro,relatime)
proc on /proc/sysrq-trigger type proc (ro,relatime)
tmpfs on /proc/acpi type tmpfs (ro,relatime)
tmpfs on /proc/kcore type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /proc/keys type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /proc/timer_list type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /proc/sched_debug type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /proc/scsi type tmpfs (ro,relatime)
tmpfs on /sys/firmware type tmpfs (ro,relatime)
```

But executing `mount` command on my php container doesn't provide any output. It may as I am mounted the local files with nginx and then using that nginx volume with php.

Comment: Is your filesystem mounted `nosuid`, which would result in the setuid bit being ignored?

Comment: @dossy I didn't get you properly. can you make it clear how to check if nosuid is mounted or not ? But the dir where composer keeps its vendor dir is mounted. E.g `./test:/var/www/test` and when I run `composer install` inside test dir it creates vendor dir inside test. Is it what you are asking ?

Comment: what's the full output of the `mount` command?

Comment: @dossy I have updated the question with output of mount. I don't see nosuid parameter  for it.

Comment: I need to see the full output of `mount`.  Specifically, where `/usr` is mounted.  Or, `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Oh, and I'm talking about executing `mount` from _inside_ the container, not the host where the container is running from.

Comment: @dossy Mount doesn't show any output on the container. It is alpine based container.

Comment: @dossy I have updated with the output of mount command now. Please have a look.

Comment: Oh, duh.  `/usr/local/bin/composer` isn't a binary executable, it's a shell script whose shebang line invokes `env` which in turn executes `php` ... and yeah, you can't `setuid` shell scripts.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166817/using-the-setuid-bit-properly

Comment: @dossy Thanks a lot for your effort. I will be looking forward to those workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `composer` program is a ascii text file, and as such the `setuid` bit has no effect on it.  Since you are kicking off the process as root, you can do something like `su www-data -c "composer ...."`

Comment: `su www-data -c "composer"` does not work for me because of this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52691797/variable-doesnt-expand-while-passing-as-a-parameter-to-docker-compose-command-i . Is there any other workaround which I can make composer script as an binary executable and set a suid?

Comment: @SkyRar not that i'd feel OK saying "do this.".  Thinking totally out of the proverbial box, copy the php-cli binary to something like `php-for-composer` and change the `composer` script(s) to use `#!/usr/bin/php-for-composer` instead of `#!/usr/bin/php`, and make the new binary `setuid`/`setgid`.  But even if that works I'd immediately remove the `setuid` version.